# Как создать глобальный массив?

Tags: java

Мне надо закинуть строки в массив, который был создан в классе.

Либо как мне создать какую-то глобальную штуку, куда мне можно будет закинуть строки?

Comment: Смотря для каких целей нужно это дело. Можно и статиками обойтись, а можно сделать через `volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тебе массив в классе:

```
class MyClass {
  ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Теперь он глобальный (статический):

```
class MyClass {
      public static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

А добавляешь строки в него так:

```
MyClass.arrayList.add("какая-то строка");
```

Так узнаёшь её размер:

```
MyClass.arrayList.size();
```

А так обращаешься по позиции:

```
MyClass.arrayList.get(0);
```

Но это не правильно, если он статический. Если массив не нужен, его надо обнулять, так как будет сидеть в памяти

```
MyClass.arrayList = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Постановка вопроса немного не понятная. Но возьмусь предположить, что вы имеете в виду доступ к массиву по классу. 
Для этого необходим статический массив в классе.

```
class MyClass {
  static int[] arr;
}
```

Доступ к этому массиву возможен из любого пакета и класса, только необходимо импортировать этот класс

```
import MyClass;
```

Доступ к массиву без экземпляра по классу

```
MyClass.arr[];
```

Comment: Хм.. А зачем импортировать класс? Он же не пакет.

Comment: @Qwertiy если он не в том же пакете